# How to keep the user from initializing a variable incorrectly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a class called PByte, which should represent an int value between 32 an 126. (PByte = Printable Byte.)
Now I want to prevent the user of the class to initializing an object incorrectly, but I don't want to throw an exception, I just want that Visual Studio doesn't compile, like it happens when you try to do this: `byte b = 256;`

```
sealed class PByte : IEquatable<PByte>, IComparable, IComparable<PByte>
{
    public PByte(int value)
    {
        /* if (value < 32 || value > 126)
            throw new ArgumentException("\"" + value + "\" is not a valid PByte-value"); */ 
        this._value = value;
    }

[...]
```

I've also implemented this:

```
[...] 

    public static implicit operator PByte(int value)
    {
    /*  if (value < 32 || value > 126)
            throw new ArgumentException("\"" + value + "\" is not a valid PByte-value"); */
        return new PByte(value);
    }
}
```

So this should also be impossible:
`PByte p = 2000;`

Comment: Code contracts maybe? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236408.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't enforce that at compile time without using code contracts. Even then, I think the code contracts only produce warnings and general puts the ownership of the problem on the calling scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can mostly do this using [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx), in combination with the editor extensions (available in the Extensions Gallery).  I'm not sure if it will fully enforce every situation, though.  (Edit: Turn on static checking in the `Code Contracts` section of your project's Properties.)

So, roughly, you can do something like this:

```
public PByte(int value)
{
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(value >= 32 && value <= 126, "\"" + value + "\" is not a valid PByte-value");
    this._value = value;
}
```